# How do I simplify this verbose ADO.NET Database Code

Tags: c#, ado.net, refactoring

Trivial question - I'm inexperienced with `C#`.

I have the following code to call a multi-parameter SQL-Server stored procedure.
It works and it is nice and explicit i.e. easy to read what is happening but it's very verbose.

Is there a standard shorter version of the following?

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(this.connString))
using(var comm = new SqlCommand(DatabaseLayer.procSendEmail,conn))
{
  comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  SqlParameter pmIsTemplate = new SqlParameter("@IsTemplate",SqlDbType.TinyInt);
  SqlParameter pmDateInsertKey = new SqlParameter("@DateInsertKey",SqlDbType.Int);
  SqlParameter pmEmailTO = new SqlParameter("@EmailTO",SqlDbType.NVarChar,1000);
  SqlParameter pmEmailBody = new SqlParameter("@EmailBody",SqlDbType.NVarChar,-1);
  SqlParameter pmEmailImportance = new SqlParameter("@EmailImportance",SqlDbType.TinyInt);
  SqlParameter pmEmailSubject = new SqlParameter("@EmailSubject",SqlDbType.NVarChar,1000);
  SqlParameter pmSuccess = new SqlParameter("@Success",SqlDbType.Bit);

  pmIsTemplate.Direction        = ParameterDirection.Input;
  pmDateInsertKey.Direction     = ParameterDirection.Input;
  pmEmailTO.Direction           = ParameterDirection.Input;
  pmEmailBody.Direction         = ParameterDirection.Input;
  pmEmailImportance.Direction   = ParameterDirection.Input;
  pmEmailSubject.Direction      = ParameterDirection.Input;
  pmSuccess.Direction           = ParameterDirection.Output;

  comm.Parameters.Add(pmIsTemplate);
  comm.Parameters.Add(pmDateInsertKey);
  comm.Parameters.Add(pmEmailTO);
  comm.Parameters.Add(pmEmailBody);
  comm.Parameters.Add(pmEmailImportance);
  comm.Parameters.Add(pmEmailSubject);
  comm.Parameters.Add(pmSuccess);

  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Have you considered using `Dapper`?

Comment: You don't need to set `ParameterDirection.Input`. It is the default.

Comment: You can `comm.Parameters.Add("@IsTemplate", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = xxx;`

Comment: You should be able to use comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(string,object).  Just be sure to do a null check, and use DBNull.Value instead of null for the object parameter.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe doing something like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(this.connString))
{
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand(DatabaseLayer.procSendEmail, conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsTemplate", SqlDbType.TinyInt));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateInsertKey", SqlDbType.Int));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailTO", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailBody", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailImportance", SqlDbType.TinyInt));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailSubject", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Success", SqlDbType.Bit) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
    }
}
```

Comment: Or even Shorter - `comm.Parameters.Add("@IsTemplate", SqlDbType.TinyInt);` Please also note that the `Add` method returns a reference to the parameter that was  just added, so you can use it to also set it's value, like in Alex's comment to the question.